# Counting function calls python

Tags: python, function, random, count, numbers

What would be the best way to count how many times the function is called so that if it is called five times, the program will stop?

```
from random import randint
from functools import wraps
randNum = randint(1,100)



userGuess = int(input('Please guess a number between 0 and 100: '))
yesNo = 'y'
while yesNo == 'y':
    while randNum != userGuess:
        def numCheck(userGuess):
            if userGuess == randNum:
               return('Well done!')
            elif userGuess > randNum:
                return('Too high!')
            else:
                return('Too low!')

        def tryAgain(numCheck):
            if numCheck == 'Well done!':
                return(numCheck(userGuess))
            else:
                return('Try again')

        print(numCheck(userGuess))
        print(tryAgain(numCheck))

        userGuess = int(input('Please guess a number between 0 and 100: '))

    yesNo = str(input('Continue? Y/N: ')).lower()
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I think the function would be `def numCheck(userGuess)`

Comment: The simplest way is to refactor into a `for _ in range(5):` loop - have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements

Comment: Why are you defining functions in a loop? Ugh.

Comment: check out `sys.settrace` and the `inspect` module

Answer (score 1):

You should avoid the functions inside your loop, just loop until the user has had five `guesses` or break in the loop if they guess correct.:

```
def main():
    randNum = randint(1,100)
    count = 0
    while count < 5:
        userGuess = int(input('Please guess a number between 0 and 100: '))
        if userGuess == randNum:
           print('Well done!')
           break
        elif userGuess > randNum:
            print('Too high!')
        else:
            print('Too low!')
        count += 1
    yesNo = input('Continue? Y/N: ').lower() # ask user to play again
    if yesNo == "y": 
        main() # restart the function if the user enters y 
    else: 
        return "Game Over"
```

Or just use `range` in range of the number of guesses allowed:

```
    for guess in range(5):
            userGuess = int(input('Please guess a number between 0 and 100: '))
            if userGuess == randNum:
               print('Well done!')
               break
            elif userGuess > randNum:
                print('Too high!')
            else:
                print('Too low!')
    yesNo = input('Continue? Y/N: ').lower()
    if yesNo == "y":
        main()
    else:
        return "Game Over"
```

Comment: +1 The function's job is to determine if a number is too high, too low, or just right, *not* to manage the control flow of its caller.

Answer (score 1):

not quite a full answer, but you probably want to check out `sys.settrace` if you want to monitor functions. This might be a little more advanced

```
>>> import sys
# start by defining a method which we will track later
>>> def blah():
...   print('blah')
... 
# we make a set of functions, such to avoid the "under the hood" functions
>>> functions = set(['blah'])
# define what we want to do on the function call
>>> def tracefunc(frame, event, args):
      # if the event is a function being called, and the function name is on our set of functions
...   if event == 'call' and frame.f_code.co_name in functions:
...     print('function called! <function {}>'.format(frame.f_code.co_name))
... 
# set our trace to the function we described above
>>> sys.settrace(tracefunc)
>>> blah()
function called! <function blah>
blah
```

Answer (score 0):

How about as a decorator that maintains a global (eww) dict? Each function is a key (fully qualified name) and the value is the maximum number of calls to that function. Each time it executes the enclosed function, it checks that the value != 0, executes the function and decrements the count.

If you need it for just one function, a less generic decorator could use a global var instead of a dict, and check-execute-decrement that value as above.

Comment: Although, in this question's specific case, managing that inside the loop is more sensible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could count to a certain number and then raise an exception to Catch.